# Flutter - google sig in | PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this question was already answer somewhere else but I am asking again because no solution fixed my issue.
All replies address the issue suggesting to do some stuff in firebase (SHA-256) and so on... **I am not using Firebase** and still facing the issue:

I am using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)
```

Below flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.10.4 on channel stable at /Users/xx/fvm/versions/3.10.4
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 682aa387cf (3 days ago), 2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0
```

Is anyone able to help?
Thanks